# Questions regarding probability density functions and distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I initially have a pdf defined as:

$f_Y(y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         cy(1-y^2) & \mbox{$0 \le y \le 1$}\\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right.$

$c$ is a constant that I must find. Now have I got it right if I integrate the function between $0$ and $1$ which gives $\frac c4$ so $c=4$ since the pdf must equal $1$. Is that correct?

I then must sketch the pdf which I wasn't sure how to do but what I have done is just graph $4y(1-y^2)$ between $0$ and $1$ and then had the $x$-axis equal to $0$ outside of this range. So the graph basically just looks like a "hump" in the middle between $0$ and $1$ - if that makes any sense at all!

I then must find and sketch the distribution function $F_Y(y)$ although I am struggling with this since when trying to integrate the function between $-\infty$ and $y$, the function does not converge so I am not sure what to do!? Have I got $c$ wrong or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that pdf integrates to 1 over the support space y in (0,1). Thus, you have correctly found c = 4. Now that you have found the explicit form of the pdf, you can find the cdf from the form of pdf. But the range of y for which pdf is non-zero lies between 0 and 1. So, in order to get the cdf F(t), you must integrate the pdf over 0 to t (since, pdf is 0 over the negative infinity to 0).

Comment: Ah right ok... so I now have $-y^2(y^2-2)$, what range would this be between? Would it remain between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Yes - the range of y in the cdf F(y) should be (0,1) because, cdf F(y) = P(Y < y) and pdf is trivially 0 outside (0,1). So, the definition of cdf only makes sense when y lies in (0,1).

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. Also, is my graph that I described correctly plotted?

Comment: Yes - the plot of the pdf has a hump between (0,1) with it touching the x-axis at x=0 and x=1. To confirm just take a look: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+4y%281%E2%88%92y%5E2%29+over+%280%2C1%29

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to drag the comments on for so long but I had one other quick enquiry, the last part asks me to let $Z=Y^2$ and then use $F_Y$ to find $F_Z$. How would I do this?

Comment: Just go by the definition. CDF of Z: $F_Z(z) = P[Z<z] = P[Y^2<z] = P[abs(Y)<sqrt(z)] = P[0 < Y < sqrt(z)] = F_Y(sqrt(z))$.